# Send a typing indicator on conversation update event Node.js

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to send a typing indicator on conversationUpdate but seems for me *session.sendTyping()* is only working within a dialog. At least I tried in Webchat and BotEmulator channels with no success. Any ideas about how to accomplish this?

Here my try:

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', async (message) => {
if (message.membersAdded) {
    for (let identity of message.membersAdded) {
        if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
            const replies = getGreetingReplies(message);
            cosmosDB.writeOnConvUpdate({ userMessage: message, botMessage: replies[0] }, message.address.conversation.id);

            bot.loadSession(message.address, async (err, session) => {
                for (let reply of replies) {
                    //var msg = new builder.Message().address(message.address).text('');
                    //msg.type = 'Typing';
                    //bot.send(msg);
                    await utilities.SendTyping(session, 3000);
                    bot.send(reply);
                }
            });

        }
    }    
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

For directline/webchat make sure to set up your bot connection on the frontend like so:

```
  botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
    secret: "<secret>",
    webSocket:true,
    sendTyping: true
  });
```

Then to actually send a sendTyping event you just have to call `session.sendTyping()` when a new message is received, or if you want to be more specific, you can call the method before something you know is going to take a while, like an API call.

The sendTyping event only works with an open webSocket, and is not supported in all channels. However it will work in webchat when using the above configuration.